# Find prime number in C#

Tags: c#, primes

Ok, I want to enter an integer from the console and check if the number is prime.
I dug up one code and I converted it to suit my needs but it is not calculating right.

```
using System;
    class PrimeNumber
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Type a number: ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine(); // Read string from console
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(line, out value)) // Try to parse the string as an integer
        {
            int x = 0;
            if (value == 1) Console.WriteLine("not prime");
            if (value == 2) Console.WriteLine("prime");
            for (int i = 3; i < value*value; i+=2)
            {
                if (value % 2 == 0) x++; break;
                if (value % i == 0) x++; break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            if (x == 0) Console.WriteLine(value + " is prime");
            else Console.WriteLine(value + " is not prime");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (..) but it's not calculating right becauuuuseeee...

Comment: What are the values you have tried?

Comment: @whoever voted to close: don't be so quick to close questions... I spotted the problem, and I can't answer because the question is closed. That's just dumb...

Comment: Your `if ( value % i == 0 ) x++;` is unreachable by the way..

Comment: I tried 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
it's working fairly well until 9. I don't know why but 9%3==0 doesn't raise x+1

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Only RobertHarvey voted to close the question. Voted for reopen.

Comment: You need braces: `{ x++; break; }`.

Comment: @user3000071, you're missing curly brackets in your `if` statements, so the `break` is always executed.

Comment: Just spotted the brackets - thanks! Though it doesn't work this way either.

Comment: And it doesn't make sense to iterate to value*value, but just to sqrt(value).

Comment: You have two problem with your code.
a) the missing curly brackets and
b) the `value * value` in the condition. This way, i will always reach the value of `value`, making the condition a match for every entered `value`. Also, I'm for reopening that question here.

Comment: @thomaslevesque it's open.

Comment: For those of you who thought the question was closed prematurely, do note that the OP's question is basically "I dug up this code from some place and changed it a little bit, but *it doesn't work.* Can you fix it for me?"  That's not a question, or even a problem statement.

Comment: When I want to find a prime number, I just google it. Maybe C# has a way of posting requests to URIs...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem", but you know this already, hopefully. "it is not calculating right" is not describing the specific problem. "I spotted the problem, and I can't answer because the question is closed." - that's not a valid argument. I can, for example, answer a question that has nothing to do with programming, but that doesn't mean it belongs here.

Comment: @Dukeling, perhaps you're right. Still, it's *very* frustrating when you spend some time writing an answer, and just before you finish, someone closes the question and you can't post the answer...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yeah, I know the feeling, although these days I mostly avoid answering questions (or attempting to do so) that don't conform to the site guidelines (and there is a little-known work-around that probably shouldn't be publicly mentioned).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (value % 2 == 0) x++; break;
if (value % i == 0) x++; break;
```

The `break` statements are **not** part of the `if`, only the `x++` is... So the `break` is **always** executed, whether or not the condition is true.

You should enclose the statements in curly brackets:

```
if (value % 2 == 0) { x++; break; }
if (value % i == 0) { x++; break; }
```

Two other problems:

- you should put `if (value % 2 == 0)` outside the loop, because it's useless to check it again at every iteration.
- you should stop iterating at `sqrt(value)` (inclusive), not `value²`. If you go to `value²`, at some point `i` will equal `value`, so `value % i` will be 0, and the number won't be considered prime.

Comment: Do you see something else because 9 seems to be prime although 9%3 is 0

Comment: @user3000071, you need to stop your loop at `sqrt(value)` inclusive, not exclusive. Otherwise it stops before it reaches 3, and doesn't detect 3 as a divisor

Answer (score 2):

Here's a efficient way of finding out if a number is prime or not.

```
static bool IsPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use eratosthenes sieve, which efficiently generate primes:
My implementation:

```
static int[] GenerateEratosthen()
    {
        bool[] e = new bool[200000];
        for (int i = 2; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j * i < 200000; j++)
            {
                e[j * i] = true;
            }
        }
        int[] p = new int[20000];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 200000; i++)
        {
            if (!e[i])
                p[k++] = i;
        }
        return p;
    }
```